# Check a string in another string in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str_1 = "Gandalf";
    string str_2 = "dal";
    for (int i = 0; i <= str_1.length() - 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= str_2.length(); j++) {
            if (str_2[j] == str_1[i]) {
                if (str_2[j + 1] == str_1[i + 1]) {
                    if (str_2[j + 2] == str_1[i + 2])
                        cout << "true";
                }
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

I can do it but if length of `str_2` is 4 characters, program doesn't work.
I want that program can work for every length of string
but how?

Comment: You want to check if `str_1` contains `str_2`? [`return str_1.find(str_2)!=std::string::npos;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: yes ,str_1 is always longer than ste_2

Comment: i have to not use find()

Comment: This is for a class or something yeah? And the idea is pretty much to implement `find`? I'll delete my answer and make a new one.

Comment: for examle: str_1="osmanyilmaz" str_2=furkan but they can be another words. but str_1 is always bigger. if str_2 is in the str_1, display true. if str_2 isn't in the str_1, display false. I can't use find()

Comment: Can you use things from `<algorithm>`?

Answer (score 2):

The function `find` below basically reproduces the behaviour of `std::string::find` (without the starting position parameter). You need to:

- loop through the outer string, and at each step:
- loop through the second string checking each character.
- If any of these fail, drop back to the outer loop.
- If we make it all the way through the inner loop, then the second string is there, and return the current position in the outer loop.
- If we run out of space in the first string, just skip the rest.

Hopefully the comments make this clear. I also include a little utility function to turn the found position into true/false, and some tests.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string::size_type find(const std::string& s1,
                            const std::string& s2)
    // return the position of s2 within s1,
    // else npos if it is not present.
{
    using size_type = std::string::size_type;
    size_type curPos = 0;
    size_type lim    = s1.size();
    size_type innerLim = s2.size();

    for (; curPos<lim; ++curPos) { // loop through s1
        if (lim < curPos+innerLim) {
            break; // not enough space left
        }
        size_type innerPos = 0;
        for(; innerPos < innerLim // loop through s2, while matching
                && curPos + innerPos < lim
                && s1[innerPos+curPos] == s2[innerPos];
                ++innerPos) ; // do nothing in the loop
        if (innerPos == innerLim) { // matched the whole loop
            return curPos;
        }
    }
    return std::string::npos; // never matched
}

bool contains(const std::string& s1,
              const std::string& s2)
{
    return find(s1, s2)!=std::string::npos;
}


int main()
{
    std::cout
        << std::boolalpha
        << contains("abc", "")      << '\n' // true
        << contains("abc", "abc")   << '\n' // true
        << contains("abc", "bc")    << '\n' // true
        << contains("abc", "abcd")  << '\n' // false
        << contains("abc", "abd")   << '\n' // false
        << contains("abc", "xyz")   << '\n';// false
}
```

This does more than what you really need, but it most closely models the "real" answer (use the facilities the language provides). Plus it makes it not a great homework answer, but contains all the clues to write your homework answer.

Comment: This space intentionally left blank. @BoBTFish makes a very important point right at the end. Note what he did. Use the idea. Understand it. Write your own simple version and submit that. Trying to submit what BoBTFish just did will either get you marked really hard for the rest of the semester because _obviously_ you're coming into the course with significant pre-existing knowledge or you'll get smacked upside the head for plagiarism. Stealing ideas is at least half of programming, but computer science kinda frowns on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str_1.length() - str_2.length(); i++) {
    bool is_same = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < str_2.length(); j++) {
        if (str[i + j] != str_2[j]) {
            is_same = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (is_same) {
        std::cout << "true" << std:endl;
    }
}
```

It iterates over every character in `str_1` and checks whether the character sequence starting at that point is the same as `str_2`.